# How can I compute an inverse transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a transformation matrix

$T = \begin{pmatrix}
0.88844717888408020 & -0.45803846513609919 & 0.029366218494823685 & 4.7974291360187735e+001 \\
-0.45857977499086372 & 0.88318824845810662 & -0.098402783267705962 & -5.6055733857639403e+001 \\
0.019136360736778883 & -0.10089242905822371 & -0.99471328404544956 & 1.9550590301593385e+000 \\
 0.0000000000000000e+000 & 0.0000000000000000e+000 & 0.0000000000000000e+000 & 1.0000000000000000e+000 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

which let's say maps A to B can I compute an inverse transformation which can map from B to A?

I have thought of finding the rotation matrix from the above Transformation  matrix which is

$\begin{pmatrix} 
 8.88447179e-01 & -4.58579775e-01 & 1.91363607e-02 & 0.00000000e+00 \\
 -4.58038465e-01 & 8.83188248e-01 & -1.00892429e-01 & 0.00000000e+00 \\
 2.93662185e-02 & -9.84027833e-02 & -9.94713284e-01 & 0.00000000e+00 \\
 4.79742914e+01 & -5.60557339e+01 & 1.95505903e+00 & 1.00000000e+00 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

and reverse its angle, but how can I reverse its angle?

Comment: This is unreadable. Please format using MathJax.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Okay thank you next time I will use this

Comment: By dropping decimals and using a common format, you would recognize that the matrices are transpose of each other.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

$$MA=B\iff A=M^{-1}B$$ and if $M$ is orthogonal, $$M^{-1}=M^T.$$

Answer (score 0):

The rank $3$ matrix

$$\mathbf{A}= \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0.888447 & -0.458038 & 0.0293662 & 47.9743 \\
 -0.45858 & 0.883188 & -0.0984028 & -56.0557 \\
 0.0191364 & -0.100892 & -0.994713 & 1.95506 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$

has a classic inverse
$$
\mathbf{A}^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1.53531 & 0.792463 & -0.0330692 & -29.1686 \\
 0.791527 & 1.52816 & -0.127807 & 47.9392 \\
 -0.0507472 & -0.139754 & -0.992988 & -3.4581 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)
.$$

The classic inverse satisfies:

$$
\mathbf{A}^{-L} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{-R} = \mathbf{I}_{4}.
$$

(Thanks to @amd for pointing out transcription error.)

---

Matrix $\mathbf{A}$

[image: A]

Matrix $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$

[image: Ap]

Comment: The lower-right entry in the OP’s matrix doesn’t appear to be zero.